# Convert xml to Key Value pair SQL Server

Tags: xml, sql-server-2012

I have an xml column with structure in SQL Server 2012

```
<root>
  <person>
    <firstName>Jon</firstName>
    <lastName>Johnson</lastName>
  </person>
```

How can I retrieve the data like

```
Key        | Value  
-------------------------------------------------------------------
First Name | Jon
Last Name  | Johnson
```

Comment: You'll be able to get keys as "firstName", "lastName" fairly easily. If you really need "First Name" and "Last Name" this gets messier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
DECLARE @input TABLE (ID INT NOT NULL, XmlData XML)

INSERT INTO @input VALUES(1, '<root>
  <person>
    <firstName>Jon</firstName>
    <lastName>Johnson</lastName>
  </person></root>')

select
    XC.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(50)'),
    XC.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM
    @input
CROSS APPLY
    XmlData.nodes('/root/person/*') AS XT(XC)
WHERE
    ID = 1
```

By using the `CROSS APPLY` on the `/nodes/person/*` XPath, you basically get an pseudo table of XML fragments - one for each sub-element of `<person>`. Use `local-name(.)` to get the *name* of the XML element, and `.` to get the value of that XML element.